# Parsing time interval strings as "Uncertain" Time Intervals

Tags: date-and-time, semantic-matching

**Problem:** I have strings of form `"[d1, d2]"` or sometimes just `[d1]` where `d1` and `d2` denote "times". I'm trying to convert these strings to their Mathematica `Around` equivalent. So for example

```
"[30min, 1hr]"
```

should be converted to

```
Around[Quantity[45, "Minutes"], Quantity[15, "Minutes"]]
```

**Attempt:** The following code snippet seems as a potential starting point for this conversion

```
StringCases["[30min, 1hr]", x : NumberString :> ToExpression[x]]
(* {30, 1} *)
```

however it only grabs raw numbers and not time quantities.

Comment: Are the designators for time, such as "m" and "hr" known?  Are there any cases of "d" (for day) or "w" for week or similar?

Comment: Mark R: Can we say that the designators should be anything that Wolfram's `SemanticInterpretation` picks up when parsing time lengths?

Comment: I think the problem is that "m" is ambiguous.  Is it "meters" or "minutes".  In your context, it is clear but I don't know that SemanticInterpretation has a context (such as time) as a qualifier.  I have code that I think does what you want but was trying to clarify before posting.

Comment: Mark R: In that case, I'll adjust my example to have `min` instead of `m` (though "m" is more convenient in my case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you.

```
timeRules = {"m" -> "Minutes", "hr" -> "Hour", "min" -> "Minutes", 
   "h" -> "Hour"};
ParseTime[timeString_] := 
  With[{numberString = First@StringCases[timeString, NumberString]}, 
   Quantity @@ {ToExpression@numberString, 
     StringDelete[timeString, numberString] /. timeRules}];
ParseTimeString[bracketedTimeString_] := 
  ParseTime[#] & /@ 
   StringSplit[bracketedTimeString, {"[", ",", ", ", "]"}];
ApproximateTime[bracketedTimeString_] := 
 With[{parsedTime = ParseTimeString[bracketedTimeString]}, 
  If[Length[parsedTime] > 1, 
   Around[Median[parsedTime], Median[parsedTime] - Min[parsedTime]], 
   First@parsedTime]]
```

Given an input of

```
aString = "[30m,1hr]"
ApproximateTime[aString]
```

It returns

```
Around[
Quantity[0.75, "Hours"], 
Quantity[15., "Minutes"]]
```

EDIT: 
Made a couple of minor changes so that I didn't assume the first element was the smallest and to handle the case where the string is something like this: "[20m]".

```
ApproximateTime["[20m]"]
(* Quantity[20, "Minutes"] *)
```

EDIT 2: 
More minor changes in case there are spaces after the comma.  And a new test case.

```
ApproximateTime[#] & /@ {"[20m,1h]", "[30m,45m]", "[45m, 2h]"}
(* {Around[
Quantity[0.6666666666666666, "Hours"], 
Quantity[20., "Minutes"]], 
 Quantity[Around[37.5, 7.5], "Minutes"], Around[
Quantity[1.375, "Hours"], 
Quantity[37.5, "Minutes"]]} *)
```